# F# piping to/from .net objects

Tags: .net, f#, piping

I've noticed difficulty in piping to/from some .NET methods.  Toy example

```
let foo = System.String [| 'a'; 'b'; 'c' |] // works
let foo = [| 'a'; 'b'; 'c' |] |> System.String // fails
// error FS0802: Invalid use of a type name and/or object constructor. 
let foo = System.String <| [| 'a'; 'b'; 'c' |] // fails the same way
let foo = [| 'a'; 'b'; 'c' |] |> new System.String // Fails
// error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression
```

I'm basically trying to figure out when you can combine piping with .NET objects and when not.   If there's a reference out there I'd love to get the link!

Comment: Your examples (except the last one, which is illegal syntax) work in F# 4. They [added support to treat constructors as functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015/). Which version of F# are you using?

Comment: I'm running Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.60610.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: Yeah, that's a really old version, F# 4 has Interactive version 14, so I'm guessing you're using F# 3 (possibly even something older)... Anyway, either you upgrade to at least Visual Studio 2015 or you have to use `|> fun chars -> System.String chars` lambdas as described in the linked blog post.

Comment: wish I could upgrade!  unfortunately running on a company desktop that is required to run VS 2012 and can't fit 2015 alongside (only 3.5 gb free space).  Still, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

As for the hang-up you're having with strings, the following link shows that support for treating constructors as functions was added to F# 4.0

https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663317-allow-to-use-class-constructors-as-functions

Another common situation that makes piping awkward from .NET libraries is that they're exposed as  `tupled` (as opposed to `curried`) function parameters, which can make partially-applying functions to pipe through more painful.  Creating curried wrappers around these clunky .NET functions is often a good work-around.

Comment: One good example of creating curried wrappers is a function I often write in my own code: `let strJoin (between:string) (parts:#seq<string>) = System.String.Join(between,parts)`. (The type annotations are necessary so that the compiler can figure out a unique overload for `System.String.Join`). Then I can write code like `listOfInts |> List.map intToHexStr |> strJoin ", " |> sprintf "[%s]"` and my result string will look like `[0x1, 0x2, 0xdeadbeef]`. Simple, easy to read, and pipeable, whereas `System.String.Join` is not pipeable.