# F# Generic Function

Tags: .net, json, f#

in [piping to/from net objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352907/f-piping-to-from-net-objects/43357496#43357496)

I learned that I could do this:

```
let jsonDeserialize json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<System.String, System.String>>(json)
```

then pipe serialized Json Key/Value pairs into jsonDeserialize.  It works well.  My next question is can I genericize the call to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?  I want to use this so that I can deserialize to other types with the same function.

I tried

```
let jsonDeserialize json mytype : 'a  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(json)
```

but then couldn't figure out how to use it.  Given a serialized JSON string I want to

```
let jsDeser = 
    jsonSerialized
    |> jsonDeserialize Dictionary<string, string>
```

or something like it, in idiomatic F#

Answer (score 3):

In F#, type arguments are specified and passed in angle brackets:

```
let jsonSerialize<'mytype> json : 'mytype = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'mytype> json

let jsDeser = jsonSerialized |> jsonDeserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Or, preferably, one doesn't specify them at all, but lets the compiler figure them out from the context:

```
let jsonSerialize json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a> json

let jsDeser : Dictionary<string, string> = jsonDeserialize jsonSerialized
```

NOTE: you have to specify the generic argument on `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, because it has a non-generic overload, which will be selected if you don't specify anything.

Comment: I think you meant `let jsonSerialize<'mytype> json : 'mytype = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'mytype> json`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: I think we can drop the return type `let jsonSerialize<'mytype> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'mytype> json`, but I don't think we can drop the type definition from the function `let jsonSerialize json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a> json`. Let me know if this compiles; I don't think the compiler will understand what you mean by `'a`.

Comment: Option 1 works nicely,  Option 2 needs help.  Since I want to pipe the results to create a map.  I have: `let jsonDeserialize2 json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a> json` followed by: `let parmMap2 =
        (let parmMapDict : ParameterDict = 
            jsonDeserialize2 jsonParms
         parmMapDict)
        |> Seq.map (|KeyValue|)
        |> Map.ofSeq` which works but doesn't look as nice as option 1